# Algorithm to detect GPS environment you're in

Tags: ios, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, gps

i need to detect in which environment the app user is in. For example is he in a forrest, or in a city, or in the near of a sea...

Therefore i just made a image from the map, calculated the average pixel and compare this color to a green, blue, brown, gray color... 
But this is very inaccurate since there could be a sea in the near but the average color isn't blueish at all. Also the comparison of colors does not always match the expectations you have.

Is there any better way to detect the environment the user is in ? Since it has to work worldwide i do not think there is any possible service which can give me reliable information about forrest, seas, maybe mountains...

Maybe someone of you has an idea how to solve this or has a hint for me.

Here you can see how i tried this until this point (its objective-c code, but i am glad for any answer, also answers that do not have anything to do with iOS app developing).

```
- (UIColor *)mergedColor
{
    CGSize size = {1, 1};
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationMedium);
    [self drawInRect:(CGRect){.size = size} blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1];
    uint8_t *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(ctx);
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:data[2] / 255.0f
                                     green:data[1] / 255.0f
                                      blue:data[0] / 255.0f
                                     alpha:1];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return color;
}

    UIColor *forrest = [UIColor greenColor];
    const CGFloat *components1 = CGColorGetComponents([[self.view mergedColor] CGColor]);
    const CGFloat *components2 = CGColorGetComponents([forrest CGColor]);

    double fDistance = sqrt(pow(components1[0] - components2[0], 2) + pow(components1[1] - components2[1], 2) + pow(components1[2] - components2[2], 2));
    double fPercentage = fDistance / sqrt(pow(255, 2) + pow(255, 2) + pow(255, 2));
```

Comment: are you trying to determine this solely by image processing, or would you be open to using Geocoding & Core Location?

Comment: i am open for any possible solution. i just thought that there would not be the database which can hold information for seas, rivers, forests worldwide... thats why i though i would make a try with image processing but like i said i welcome any other ideas !

Answer (score 2):

This idea for a solution *does not involve* image processing.

But if you know your latitude and longitude (and this is easy to get from CoreLocation), you can pass it to a Geocoding service.

For example, when I look at Google's Geocoding API, I see a section for ["Address Types and Address Component Types"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types), and types include:

- `natural_feature` indicates a prominent natural feature.
- `airport`
  indicates an airport.
- `park` indicates a named park.
- `point_of_interest`
  indicates a named point of interest. Typically, these "POI"s are
  prominent local entities that don't easily fit in another category
  such as "Empire State Building" or "Statue of Liberty."

So there may be enough in that API for you to work with.

Comment: thanks i will have a look at that and give feedback in this thread if this api returns enough information for my needs

Comment: i just fired some example request to the api and it looks like it isn't really what could help me. It just doesn't have the information i need. But i might have found something from openstreetmap. i will expand my post if this helps me..

Comment: I found something using the nominatim api from openstreetmap. Here you can find a lot of search keys like forests, water, etc.. and i think it will give me exactly what i need :) http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases/EN